# Run Spring boot .jar file with spring.config.location with replace values of application.properties?

Tags: java, spring

When I run a Spring boot application from command line with `--spring.config.location=another.properties`, values in `another.properties` will be overridden the values in `application.properties` ?

For example:

If there is a value **`spring.datasource.url`** in `application.properties`, but not in `application.properties`. So the value is taken from `another.properties` or undefined ?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I tried it. When the values is not in another.properties, app use the value in application.properties. It seems that application.properties is default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It replaces.
The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) states :

> If you don’t like application.properties as the configuration file
>   name you can switch to another by specifying a spring.config.name
>   environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location using
>   the spring.config.location environment property (comma-separated list
>   of directory locations, or file paths).

Now, nobody prevents you from declaring multiple properties in `spring.config.location` value :

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,classpath:/another.properties
```

In this way, `another.properties` overrides properties also present in `application.properties`.